# How to re-arrange a HashMap?

Tags: java, hashmap, treemap

How to  re-arrange a HashMap? I want to know if it is possible to order this by date.

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> newsliste;
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("date", "01-10-2001");
map.put("name", "yoan");
newsliste.add(map);   
HashMap<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("date", "11-5-2001");
map.put("name", "Rom");
newsliste.add(map1);
HashMap<String, String> map2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("date", "01-05-2003");
map.put("name", "Nico");
newsliste.add(map2);
HashMap<String, String> map3 = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("date", "13-10-2001");
map.put("name", "moup");
newsliste.add(map3);
```

Comment: You can't have duplicate keys in a `HashMap`...

Comment: You should create a class having `Date` and `String name` as fields.

Comment: @arshajii You mean `can't`.

Comment: @RohitJain Yes, that was a typo; edited.

Comment: What you probably have are several objects with fields `date` and `name`. Also, you can't "order" a `HashMap`. It is a hash table, the itens' order in the table are defined by the hash value of the itens' keys. Maybe you want a `HashSet`.

Comment: A HashMap is an associative container which allows to retrieve the value associated to the **specific** key... Only one value for a given key. Here, the "date" and "name" keys are overwritten over and over again

Comment: You basically need to sort your Map by values. Check this link out for the same: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/how-to-sort-a-mapkey-value-on-the-values-in-java 
Also, you can't have duplicate keys in a Map.

Comment: In addition to all that, you can't 'rearrange' or re-order a HashMap. It doesn't have a defined order in the first place. See the Javadoc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really create a class with a `date` and `name` field. In addition, the `date` field should be a `java.util.Date` rather than a `String`.

This being said, you can use [`Collections.sort(list, comparator)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29) to sort your list:

```
final DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-M-yyyy");
Collections.sort(newsList, new Comparator<Map<String, String>>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Map<String, String> left, Map<String, String> right) {
        return dateFormat.parse(left.get("date")).compareTo(dateFormat.parse(right.get("date")));
    }
});
```

Comment: +1 Drat, you beat me to this.  I'll delete my answer.  BTW, a String works for a sortable Date field if he changes to a YYYY-MM-DD format.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the easiest way to implement what you are looking for is the simply

```
map.put("01-10-2001", "yoan");
```

This way you can find individual birthdays based on what is entered by using the

```
map.keySet();
```

command. Then you can find the birthday key, or whatever.

This might not be the best iteration if you are lookin for multiple values.

If you are you might want to use a hashmap of dates and a set as the value... if you really want a hashmap.

then you can use a more dynamic bucket where a date can pull a set of names and you can store whatever in there.

Hope that helps.

Comment: If you use an actual java.util.Date as the key. or use a better format for the date (YYYY-MM-DD) you could sort by the date very easily too.

Comment: @user949300
Very true. Don't why I overlooked that.

Comment: But, as others have mentioned, if a date is not unique there are issues.

Comment: that's why I'd suggest a alternate structure or a hashmap <date, set<names>.

Comment: Good point, a MultiMap works here.

Answer (score 0):

Sure.  Write a `Comparator<Map<String,String>>` which sorts the list however you want, and use `Collections.sort(newsliste, new MyComparator())` to sort it.  You might want to parse the dates and put Date objects or similar into your `Map`, since a naive sort-by-string-value will not work for dates in different years.